I am in the process of converting an uninsulated block industrial building into my residence. Any suggestions based on my proposed wall assembly?
On the border of US Climate Zones 4 and 5, the building is slab on grade and interestingly has 2 slabs, one on top of the other with a plastic barrier between them as illustrated.  The existing concrete block walls are painted inside and out.  I'm proposing to add the 2" XPS rigid insulation on the interior, and then frame 2x4 walls interior to that, insulating further with unfaced fiberglass.  I'm hoping to get some advice on whether this wall assembly will be a problem from a moisture/vapor standpoint.  And if there may be water (possibly collecting at the foot of the wall assembly), how can I ensure it finds its way out?  Note the small gap between the edge of the 2012 slab and the block wall, and the fact that the slab barrier does not extend up the wall at all.



There will be a significant thermal bridge at the junction of the slab and the wall. Can you insulate from the outside? What is Climate Zones 4 and 5? According to the internet it's either tropical or polar XD How much heating and aircon will you use?

@bobflux I cannot insulate from outside unfortunately. I know about the thermal bridge issue with the slab.  I may eventually insulate outside just below grade, going several feet down to possibly help a tiny bit.  Regarding climate zones, refer to: https://basc.pnnl.gov/images/iecc-climate-zone-map

Might want to pay a bit more for rockwool to avoid some potential fiberglass+moisture problems.

Correct assumption NOT installing the typical 4 mil poly vapor barrier over the fiberglass Insulation. It would  trap water vapors gassed by the block wall.

Yeah, you want the wall to be able to dry and putting a vapor barrier on the inside will just block that up.  Never mind the disaster it'd cause as soon as you turned the air-con on!
